# How to write multi rewrite rule according to url parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two url formats:

```
/images/www/en/news/editor/2017/1483346245-index.jpeg
```

And:

```
/images/www/news/editor/2017/1483346245-index.jpeg
```

The difference is in the language prefix; note the `en/` segment in the first URL.

My rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(fa|en|ar|fr|de)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /file/image?website=$1&language=$2&preset=$4&name=$6 [L,R=302,QSA]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /file/image?website=$1&preset=$3&name=$5 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

But only the second rule is working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Mention clearly how you want to be redirected. Write the URL's that you want to be redirected to with the explicit values in the query string.

Comment: Is your htaccess located in images folder?